# Performance issues with JQGrid on INIT and on RELOAD

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've couple of questions on Performance of JQGrid (4.5.4) with JQuery 1.8.2 version in our environment. 
But to make it simple, i'm starting with below questions:

1. What are the best FREE recommended versions of JQGrid to use to avoid Performance issue?
2. Does the end-user's machine(desktop or laptop) configuration influences the performance of JQGrid load and reload?
3. What are the parameters to avoid or use to handle performance issues?
4. One major observation, on the initial load of JQGrid takes X time with Y MB of data loaded, and when we reload (on filter) the same grid it takes 2X time to load the same Y MB of data.

**JQGrid code used to load initially:**

```
    $grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'Data.htm?load=init',
    autowidth: true,
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8', 'Col9'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'col1',
        width: 65
    }, {
        name: 'col2',
        width: 80
    }, {
        name: 'col3',
        width: 75
    }, {
        name: 'col4',
        width: 52
    }, {
        name: 'col5',
        width: 65
    }, {
        name: 'col6',
        width: 80
    }, {
        name: 'col7',
        width: 100
    }, {
        name: 'col8',
        width: 100
    }, {
        name: 'col9',
        width: 100
    }],
    cmTemplate: {
        sortable: false
    },
    recordtext: "Showing {1} of {2}",
    rowNum: 15,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    pager: '#pager',
    width: "1100",
    gridview: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    rownumbers: false,
    sortname: 'invdate',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: 'asc',
    height: 'auto',
    loadonce: true
}); //eof-jqgrid
```

**JQGrid code to reload the grid ussing trigger function:**

```
  var sForm = $('#form').serialize();
  $("#grid").jqGrid('clearGridData').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
      url: 'Data.htm?load=filter&' + sForm,
      datatype: 'json'
  }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

So i've no clue on what is influensing the reload to take double time? How can I avoid this, do we need to pass any additional params on reload?

The model I've built is, I get a JSON formatted string from server and supplied to JQGrid. And now JQGrid is taking huge amount of time to get it loaded.

Comment: Can any one provide suggestion and comments on my query, thanks!

Comment: Hope if any once had similar issues on JQGrid.trigget('realod'), if yes please let me know the changes I would need to make to my program. Thanks in advance!